# Restrict orientation of view controller when using a static UITableView

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I've set up a static `UITableView` with iOS Designer (IB in Objective-C world). But the orientation is changed despite I want to restrict it.

I've done the following:

In **Properties** under *Simulated Metrics* I chose *Portrait* as *Orientation*. Than I'm implementing the following functions for my `UITableViewController`:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
{
    return false;
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
}
```

`GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` is called and I return *Portrait* but the view is still rotated. What I'm missing?

**Edit:**

I've used the approach discussed in [View Orientation](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/40992/#Comment_40992). This works for my view controllers. The static `UITableViewController` is pushed in this way on the stack:

```
this.PresentViewController (new UINavigationController(myStaticTableViewController), true, null);
```

Here the standard implementation of `UINavigationController` is used. I also tried it with my `CustomNavigationController` which implements

```
partial class CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
{

    public CustomNavigationController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
    {
        return TopViewController.ShouldAutorotate();
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ()
    {
        return TopViewController.PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ();
    }
}
```

but I can't do something like this

```
this.PresentViewController (new CustomNavigationController(myStaticTableViewController), true, null);
```

because it cannot convert my table view controller to `IntPtr`. Perhaps that's the reason why it doesn't respect the interface orientation. What solutions do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I only had to add another constructor as stated in the linked thread. Now my `CustoMNavigationController` looks like this:

```
partial class CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
{

    public CustomNavigationController(UIViewController rootViewController) : base(rootViewController)
    {

    }

    public CustomNavigationController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
    {
        return TopViewController.ShouldAutorotate();
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ()
    {
        return TopViewController.PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ();
    }
}
```

Now I can use

```
this.PresentViewController (new CustomNavigationController(myStaticTableViewController), true, null)
```

and everything works as expected.