# Restrict orientation per view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, xamarin.ios, orientation

I want to say in each view controller which orientation he supports and restrict it to them. This is what I tried:

- Use a custom navigation controller like in one of my [old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011521/restrict-orientation-of-view-controller-when-using-a-static-uitableview), but that doesn't seem to work anymore. The solution is similar to [iOS 6 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate not getting called for navigation controllers pushed viewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13619579/426227)
- I also tried [Setting Orientation in Xamarin iOS](http://niftit.com/setting-orientation-in-xamarin-ios/), but the app crashes on the `RootViewController`. I get a `NullReferenceException` here.
- Furthermore I tried [IOS 8 : Restricting orientation on a View Controller](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kqfFfKHc4WgJ:shrixamarin.blogspot.com/2014/10/ios-8-restricting-orientation-on-view.html+&cd=2&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=us) from the deleted blog from Shri Chakraborty (shrixamarin). Here the app also crashes if I use `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:`, because the `RootViewController` is null. The solution seems to be similar to [How do I restrict orientation per view controller in iOS7 in a navigation controller hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925127/426227)

None of the solutions seems to work. Or do I miss something important? How can I restrict the orientation that view controller A is landscape only, view controller B is portrait only and view controller C can be shown in all available orientations?

Answer (score 1):

Overriding `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()` in your view controller should solve the problem:

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()     {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight;
}
```

The orientations you return here will be intersected with the app's allowed orientations (project properties) or with what you allow in your app delegate. So be sure to specify *all* orientations there or the *maximum set* of orientations you want to support.

See here for [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I removed the override for `ShouldAutorotate()` in my view controllers and now it works. I'm using my [*CustomNavigationController*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26012695/426227). One more question though: If I navigate from view controller A (only landscape) to view controller B (only portrait) then the orientation doesn't update. I'm in landscape despite view controller B only allows portrait. Only after rotation the behavior is correct again.

Comment: How do you navigate from A to B? `UINavigationController` push?

Comment: Yes `NavigationController.PushViewController (testViewController, true);`

Comment: Have you tried using a plain `UINavigationController` to see if your custom one creates the problem?

Comment: If I use the default `UINavigationController` then my orientations are not restricted. This does only work if the view controller is the current top most view controller (so no navigation controller used at all). That's the reason why I used my custom navigation controller, which queries the top most view controller if it should rotate or not.

Comment: Do you had some time looking into this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what else to try. The solution I gave you should not require any changes on the navigation controller.

Comment: Would it help if I provide a sample project to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Not really. I just made a demo project and I see now what your issue is. Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064900/how-do-i-force-a-specific-uiinterfaceorientation-on-an-individual-view-in-a-uina - my thinking is that it is not good design to have one view controller that will enforce rotation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree with you on that point. My application would look nicer if one could force the orientation. Now the system has to calculate the layout twice. I also think Apple is doing that in one of their applications (calendar on iPhone). Now I'll try to do it without enforcement and perhaps that will be enough.